Magento 2.4.6-p4 product images have washed colours
Today I discover something strange. It seems that magento renders the images with different colours in admin than in frontend. Here is a jpg image compared:

Left image is shown in admin. The right one is in frontend. You notice that colours in the right one are washed. Image is a jpg file. Not sure what is going on but I suspect that after product image is uploaded to admin, magento starts to copy it to cache folders. There it should be the problem
We use magento 2.4.6-p4. Server is up to ubuntu 22 with imagick installed for converting images.
I am not sure how to handle this. Anyone else with same issues please?

Perhaps turning off Enable Image Optimization inside Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System might help? Magento auto-optimizes images by default, and it's possible the coloring is getting messed up in the interim...
EDIT:
After some more research it seems that this happens with JPG images only. You can convert from JPG to PNG with an online tool, and upload your image as a PNG, it should retain the correct coloring.

This is due to upload image quality configuration into the magento
you can go into the Stores > Settings > Configuration.
In the left panel, expand Advanced and choose System and Expand  the Images Upload Configuration section. To change default settings, you may need to deselect the Use system value checkbox. To enable, make sure Enable Frontend Resize is set to Yes. Enter a Quality setting between 1 to 100%. Set the Maximum Width in pixels for the image.Set the Maximum Height in pixels for the image.


these settings are already placed. This is not the issue....It must something with certain images and their ICC colour profile....

Okay, so you already tried setting the quality to 100%, but the issue persists, correct? Also, as you mentioned, it works well with certain images, which means it functions correctly with other images, right?

Yes. It seems that some images not having the problem. It is definetely the colours and not the quality of the compression. this corrects the problem but not working with magento latest https://github.com/superdav42/magento-image-quality
